# Load MockReposity object with MockRepository property through Spring

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rhino-mocks, spring.net

Versions: C# 4.0, Spring.Net 1.3.2, RhinoMocks 3.6.1

Given these two interfaces:

```
public interface IDivisionSelectView
{
    // ...
}

public interface ILoginView
{
    IDivisionSelectView DivisionSelectView { get; }

    // ...
}
```

I'm trying with Spring.Net to use the `Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateMock<>()` factory to create a proxy object for `ILoginView` which has its *DivisionSelectView* property auto-set to an `IDivisionSelectView` proxy (using the same factory). Here's the Spring XML:

```xml
<object id="IDivisionSelectView"
        type="Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository, Rhino.Mocks"
        factory-method="GenerateMock&lt;[Asm.Ns.IDivisionSelectView, Asm]>"
        singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg name="argumentsForConstructor">
    <list element-type="System.Object, mscorlib">
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>

<object id="ILoginView"
        type="Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository, Rhino.Mocks"
        factory-method="GenerateMock&lt;[Asm.Ns.ILoginView, Asm]>"
        singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg name="argumentsForConstructor">
    <list element-type="System.Object, mscorlib">
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
  <property name="DivisionSelectView" ref="IDivisionSelectView">
  </property>
</object>
```

Here's the calling C# code:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = new XmlApplicationContext(
    "assembly://Asm/Asm/spring.xml");
ContextRegistry.RegisterContext(ctx);

ILoginView view = ctx.GetObject("ILoginView") as ILoginView;
```

Here's the error I get:

`Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException was unhandled by user code`

Message=Error creating object with name 'ILoginView' defined in 'assembly [Asm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [Asm.spring.xml] line 14' : Initialization of object failed : 'DivisionSelectView' node cannot be resolved for the specified context [Castle.Proxies.ILoginViewProxy4fa9c3fa65ca497bb09ce6358d876e4d].

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The DivisionSelectView property on ILoginView doesn't have a setter.

Comment: That was by design. I'm no longer using `Rhino.Mocks` for this stuff, and I might not have fully understood everything involved when I posted this question. Now I would simply mock the getter to return a Spring-loaded object. However the question as posed is essentially about what you have suggested - if it's possible to inject that object with Spring without a public setter.